# How to pass an object associated with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a CustomTableViewCell where there is an image. This image is associated with **UITapGestureRecognizer**.

When i click in this image i need pass the object, based on the cell and indexPath, to the selector, like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTotal") as TotalTableViewCell

  let schedulle = schedulleList[indexPath.row] as Schedulle

  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "edit:")
  tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
  tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

  //simulation code - here i need pass the object clicked
  tap.AssociatedObject = schedulle
  cell.imgSchedulleEdit.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

 return cell
}

func edit(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   //simulation code getAssociated Object
   let schedulle = sender.getAssociatedObject as Schedulle
}
```

I know, this is not good, generally i use didSelectRow, but this app needs a click on specific image of cell.

Schedulle have attributes:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Schedulle: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var createdDate: NSDate
  @NSManaged var message: String
}
```

Comment: I would like Know, who mark my question with down vote. This question is real and important for me. I asked for something that´s not the better way. After the answer i found the way. Jus for this i made this question.

Comment: I appreciate that you explain, why my question deserved a downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the gesture recognizer in the dequeue cell method, add it in the TotalTableViewCell subclass with the cell as the target, then provide a delegate callback to your view controller, along the lines of `totalTableViewCellDidTapImage(cell: TotalTableViewCell)`

Now in your view controller you can get the index path for this row by using

```
func totalTableViewCellDidTapImage(cell: TotalTableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    let schedulle = schedulleList[indexPath.row] as Schedulle
    // do stuff with schedulle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `UIImageView`, use `UIButton`, and use the button's method `setImage(_:forState:)` to set your image. Then you can you activate the event using `addTarget`, which will pass an instance of the button to the action.

Answer (score 0):

According @someGuy and @backsquare, i'll post the complete answer:

I changed for button instead of button.

1 - I defined the **protocol**, in custom table view cell:

```
protocol SchedulleEdit : NSObjectProtocol{
  func totalTableViewCellEdit(cell: TotalTableViewCell)
}
```

2 - i created the var, in custom table view cell to receive the **delegate**

```
protocol SchedulleEdit : NSObjectProtocol{
  func totalTableViewCellEdit(cell: TotalTableViewCell)
}

class TotalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  var delegate : SchedulleEdit? = nil
 ...
}
```

3 - i defined the function to capture selected cell and send it to the view controller that implement our protocol.

```
protocol SchedulleEdit : NSObjectProtocol{
  func totalTableViewCellEdit(cell: TotalTableViewCell)
}

class TotalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   var delegate : SchedulleEdit? = nil
  ...
 } 

 @IBAction func edit(sender: UIButton) {
   self.delegate?.totalTableViewCellEdit(self)

 }
}
```

4 - In ViewController or in TableViewController, depends your case, i implemented the protocol **SchedulleEdit**:

```
class TotalViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, SchedulleEdit{
  ...
}
```

5 - In  **cellForRowAtIndexPath** i set the delegate for:

```
class TotalViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, SchedulleEdit{

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTotal") as TotalTableViewCell

   cell.delegate = self
   ...
 }

}
```

6 - Finally i implemented the required method of our protocol:

```
class TotalViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, SchedulleEdit{

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTotal") as TotalTableViewCell

   cell.delegate = self
   ...
 }

 func totalTableViewCellEdit(cell: TotalTableViewCell) {
   let indexPath = self.tblTotal.indexPathForCell(cell)
   let row = indexPath?.row
   let schedulle = self.schedulleList[row!] as Schedulle
   println(schedulle.message)
 }
}
```